# "updated" graphics card driver won't boot Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, graphics, radeon

I picked up a link in Google saying "updated drivers."  My graphics card is old, an ATI (AMD) Radeon hd 4670? definitely 4600 series.

From looking around Recovery mode I found out that the drivers were automatically backed up.  I hope this will be solved by restoring the backup.

I may also be able to get the drivers from AMD or maybe the manufacturer.  Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On screen login: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

1. your login and your password
2. `sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*`
3. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`
4. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: On step 1, I get prompted for my hard disk logon and password.  Not sure what they are.  Maybe the computer ID.  I don't know the login or the pw.  @YolatengO

Comment: I got through the login.  I executed step 2 and 3.  Then a message box came up saying there was an internal error in Ubuntu.  I looked at the error listing and there were a few things about x-server and radeon.  Is there another route we can go?

Comment: another route:  wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection

Comment: Or Which desktop environment do you use? Unity or gnome. If this is a fresh install Ubuntu 14.04 .  Xubuntu is more stable for the old graphics card . ( by experiment ;-) )